# Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException. while getting TransitiveMemberOf

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

I'm seen **System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection reset by peer error** doing the call to retrieve groups using TransitiveMemberOf method from Microsoft.Graph.dll.

```
 public async Task<List<AdGroup>> GetAllGroupsByUserId(string userId, CancellationToken token)
    {
        _client = GraphConnection.GetGraphClient(_config);
        var memberships = new List<AdGroup>();
        try
        {
            IUserTransitiveMemberOfCollectionWithReferencesRequest? next = null;
            do
            {
                IUserTransitiveMemberOfCollectionWithReferencesPage data;
                if (next == null)
                {
                    var id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                    var options = new List<Option>()
                    {
                        new QueryOption("$top", "999"),
                        new HeaderOption("client-request-id", id)
                    };

                    data = await _client.Users[userId].TransitiveMemberOf.Request(options).Select("id,displayName").GetAsync(token);
                }
                else
                {
                    data = await next.GetAsync(token);
                }

                next = data.NextPageRequest;
                if (data.CurrentPage.Count == 0)
                    break;

                var foundGroups = data.CurrentPage
                    .Select(i =>
                    {

                        if (i is Group group)
                            return new AdGroup()
                            {
                                Id = group.Id,
                                Name = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(group.DisplayName) ? group.AdditionalData?["displayName"].ToString() ?? "" : group.DisplayName
                            };
                        if (i is DirectoryRole role)
                            return new AdGroup()
                            {
                                Id = role.Id,
                                Name = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(role.DisplayName) ? role.AdditionalData?["displayName"].ToString() ?? "" : role.DisplayName
                            };
                        return null;
                    })
                    .Where(g => g != null && Constants.CONTAINS_LIST.Any(c => g.Name.Contains(c, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)));
                    
                if (foundGroups != null)
                    memberships.AddRange(foundGroups);

            } while (next != null);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError(e, "GetAllGroupsByUserId error");
        }
        return memberships;
    }
```

I tried to run the code from Azure VM ( I have Linux OS there) as well as from my local machine (Windows OS). Now I'm checking the load of VM because the code is running in threads and thinking about what can be wrong.

I've also created a ticken in Azure Portal and I have the following answer from the Microsoft:

> This error is not coming from Microsoft Graph rather from your clients
> socket (otherwise meaning a network error)
>
> For these errors, you must start with your networking team to
> investigate. There could be a number of networking reasons i.e. your
> Firewall, Proxy, Loadbalancer, network bandwidth throttling.

That answer didn't help me a lot, but I'm trying to investigate futher.

I will appreciate any help, thanks

Answer (score 1):

In case if someone face the similar issue, I posted the information which helped me to resolve it:

1. Increase the number of cores on VM from 4 to 16
2. Decrease the number of tasks from 200 to 100 which were doing the call to MS Graph and some logic
3. Initialize a new MS Graph client on each iteration inside of the method GetAllGroupsByUserId